I don't get how to initialize tridimensional arrays
So I'm doing a video game and i need some coordinates [2](x,y), but there are 3 zones [3][2], and there are 3 rooms [3][3][2]. So i chose a tridimensional array. I know there is a better way to give each of them different values
What I did:
zonasDeInteraccion[1][1][1] = 10; //x
zonasDeInteraccion[1][1][2] = 5; //y
zonasDeInteraccion[1][2][1] = 20; //x
zonasDeInteraccion[1][2][2] = 5;  //y
zonasDeInteraccion[1][3][1] = 30; //x
zonasDeInteraccion[1][3][2] = 5;  //y
zonasDeInteraccion[2][1][1] = 30; //x
zonasDeInteraccion[2][1][2] = 7;   //y
zonasDeInteraccion[2][2][1] = 4; //x
zonasDeInteraccion[2][2][2] = 23;  //yd
zonasDeInteraccion[2][3][1] = 45; //x
zonasDeInteraccion[2][3][2] = 5;  //y
zonasDeInteraccion[3][1][1] = 35; //x
zonasDeInteraccion[3][1][2] = 0;  //y 
zonasDeInteraccion[3][2][1] = 1; //x
zonasDeInteraccion[3][2][2] = 11;  //y
zonasDeInteraccion[3][3][1] = 4; //x
zonasDeInteraccion[3][3][2] = 44;  //y

What I suppose it is done:
zonasDeInteraccion[3][3][2] = {{{{10,5}},{{20,5},{}},{{},{},{}},{{},{},{}}} 

But I get really confused

Array indexes start at 0 and not 1. So, you are overflowing the array in all three dimensions.

For the coordinates, I might consider a struct with x and y members rather than an array of 2 elements..

Try a struct: struct point { int x; int y; }; struct point zones[3][3] That's a 2d array. Much easier to handle.

If you're confused by putting the initializer all on a single line, then don't do that.  Split it up into multiple lines instead:
int zonasDeInteraccion[3][3][2] = {
  {
    { 10, 5 },
    { 20, 5 },
    { 30, 5 }
  },
  {
    { 30, 7 },
    { 4, 23 },
    { 45, 5 }
  },
  {
    { 35, 0 },
    { 1, 11 },
    { 4, 44 }
  }
};


as the comments have pointed out, array indexing in C starts at 0, not 1. Also, it might be much easier to have a point struct rather than an array. something like
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} point;

then you can do
point zones[3][3] = {0};
point[0][0].x = 10;
point[0][0].y = 5;
...

